# Algorithm: How to evenly distribute different colored balls?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, combinatorics

Let's say I have some number of different colored balls. For the sake of an example, let's assume 4 red balls, 4 blue balls and 2 green balls. If I want to evenly distribute these balls so that the most consistent distance between two balls of the same color is maintained I could have the following sequence:

R-B-G-R-B-R-B-G-R-B

Even though Blue and Red Balls aren't always the same distance from their counterparts, they are arranged in such a way that keeps their distances consistent while also maintaining consistency for the Green Balls

In the case of 6 red balls, 5 blue balls, and 3 green balls, I could have something like:

R-B-R-G-B-R-B-G-R-B-R-G-R

I'm not exactly sure what the criteria for "most consistent distance between two balls of the same color" would be but is there some kind of algorithm or generalized solution that would solve this? What is the formal name of this problem, if this is the case?

Comment: Wouldn't GRBRBRBRBG or RGRBRBRBGB be more consistent ? Distance between R's is always 2, between B's it's always 2, and between G's it's "always" 9 (or 7).

Answer (score 0):

This problem is similar to drawing of line in nD-space (here 3D). So you can use Bresenham/DDA-like algorithms to generate sequence with fair item distribution (instead of fair distribution of pixel shifts in ever dimension). Arbitrary [found example](http://members.chello.at/easyfilter/bresenham.html)
*(I have not checked its correctness - perhaps division `dm/2` might produce worse results than error doubling)*:

```
void plotLine3d(int x0, int y0, int z0, int x1, int y1, int z1)
{
   int dx = abs(x1-x0), sx = x0<x1 ? 1 : -1;
   int dy = abs(y1-y0), sy = y0<y1 ? 1 : -1; 
   int dz = abs(z1-z0), sz = z0<z1 ? 1 : -1; 
   int dm = max(dx,dy,dz), i = dm; /* maximum difference */
   x1 = y1 = z1 = dm/2; /* error offset */

   for(;;) {  /* loop */
      setPixel(x0,y0,z0);
      if (i-- == 0) break;
      x1 -= dx; if (x1 < 0) { x1 += dm; x0 += sx; } 
      y1 -= dy; if (y1 < 0) { y1 += dm; y0 += sy; } 
      z1 -= dz; if (z1 < 0) { z1 += dm; z0 += sz; } 
   }
}
```

Replace `x1-x0` by  the first color count, `y1-y0` by the second and so on. Output corresponding color in successful if-conditions:

`{x1 -= dx; if (x1 < 0) { x1 += dm; x0 += sx;`**HERE**}